# Method not allowed (405) Must be one of: GET - Slim3 + Apache + AWS

Tags: php, apache, slim, put, slim-3

I have been struggling with this for some time and don't know the what I am doing wrong.

I am using Slim3 (with LAMP) behind an Apache server. HTTP `GET` and `POST` works just fine. However, `PUT` and `DELETE` throws this weird error.

`Method not allowed
Method not allowed. Must be one of: GET`

And this is the `header` on postman which says - `Allow -> GET`. What is setting this? Feel it is an Apache configuration, however, I don't know how to fix this. I am running my API on AWS (Linux).

[image]

Here is my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Route to `/api/v1/spark/warranty/3` must be declared with `put()` to be able to use PUT

```
$app->put('/api/v1/spark/warranty/3', function() {
   ....
});
```

and for DELETE, with `delete()`

```
$app->delete('/some/other/url/api', function() {
   ....
});
```

See [Slim 3 Route documentation](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html).

Comment: yes indeed, I have defined my SLIM routes like how you have mentioned. I dont believe routes is an issue. Can you think of any other things that might be missing?